# wpf properties not set after initializecomponent

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a problem concerning properties that are set in xaml.
I've made a user control with a dependency property 'MidiChanel'.
I set the value of this property to 10 in xaml.
In the constructor of the user control, I need this value to add it to a dictionary and to pass the value to a child class of my user control.

The problem is, that in the constructor, even after calling initializecomponents, the property stil has its default value, and not the value, set in xaml.
In fact, it does't gets set at all.

If I change the 'MidiChanel' proprty to a normal property, the value gets set, but it's not initializecomponents of the userControl that sets the value, but initializecomponents of the main window. 
Call stack = Main.InitializeComponents, Constructor of userControl (values are not yet available), Setter of 'MidiChanel' gets set. (by who?, call stack says Main.InitializeComponents).

I'm a winforms developer and find all this pretty strange. 
After Main.InitializeComponents, I could loop over all userControls in the main page, and do everything here, but that seems a strange thing to do.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

you can set a callback method that will be raised when your dependenyProperty changed

```
   public int SomeProp
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SomePropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomePropProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SomeProp.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProp", typeof(int), typeof(yourOwnerclass), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomePropertyChnaged)));

    public static void OnSomePropertyChnaged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as yourOwnerclass).SomeFunction();
    }
```

Comment: This is ok to do stuff when a property is set, but I want to do things when all its properties have been set.  (What you would expect after initializecomponents has been called.)

Comment: maybe you should consider doing it in Loaded event

Comment: That's indeed excactly what I've done.  On the page.Loaded event, I loop over my controls, and do everything here.  Works ok, but from a point of view of a winforms developer, it seems odd to do this.  Thanks for all the input.